# Is there any way to save additional information in HTML tag?

Tags: html

I created multiple buttons, for each created button I want to save some information in an attribute so that I can use it when the button is clicked.

Is there any attribute in HTML button that I can store information to use it at some point?

Comment: the data-* attribute for instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own using the new [`data-*`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) custom data attributes (see [w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute)). What comes at the `*` is up to you (as long as it is valid HTML of course):

```
<button id="x123"
        data-some-attr="I like this"
        data-what-about-this="I like it too"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the `data-attributes`, for example [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) you can find more info.

Example from linked page:

```
<li class="user" data-name="John Resig" data-city="Boston" data-lang="js" data-food="Bacon">...</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduced the `data-` attribute just for this. So if you were to store a button number, you would call it `data-callNum` or something similar.

You can read more up on it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

As a warning with JS, you can't just use the usual `.` to access the member, due to the `-` which will be interpreted as a minus operation. So instead of `button.data-attr` you have to do `button.getAttribute('data-attr')`.

Comment: Please, no w3schools.com links, it´s a bad source.

Comment: Some like it, some hate it. I personally have never figured out why people hate it. It may not be good for learning, but I've never had any problems using it as a reference.

Comment: @David: Well, sometimes the information is not very accurate or totally wrong. They had their best time.

Comment: Quality of information in there is low, there are many better sources than w3schools which seems to be st. official due to domain name (W3C vs. W3S).

Comment: Personally, I've never had an issue with any information I've gotten off of that site. I welcome an example though.

Comment: Perhaps a more [authoritative source](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) will serve?